# jQuery mobile link multiple html documents

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mobile

I have multiple html documents that share one css stylesheet (not multiple page div sections in one html) for web app project using jQuery mobile framework. 
All html documents work fine individually but if one page opens from another page's link, all the script and styles do not apply anymore. Is there any way to keep each html page refreshed whenever they are linked? I have tried `data-ajax="false"` and `rel="external"` in `<a>` tags, but they did not work. Your help will be appreciated!

yes, each html has plugins links in the head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/custom.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" /> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(event){ 
//custom script in each html 
});
```

And htmls are linked with  tags in their  tags:

```
<a href="page1.html">page 1</a> 
<a href="page2.html">page 2</a> 
<a href="page3.html">page 3</a>
```

The links work but custom stylesheet and script are not applied anymore when a new html opens from previous page. If I add data-ajax="false" or rel="external" in the  tags, even the links do not work anymore.

Thanks for looking into the code!

PS. Sorry that I am not familiar with jsfiddle and copied my code for two separate html files. If I open page2.html first, the slider works fine. But if I open it from the menu in page1.html, the slider does not work.

This is page1.html:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).toggle(
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "block");},
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "none");
      });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#cfcfcf;
    display:none;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main{
    margin: 50px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="page1">
        <div class="navigation">
            <a class="menu" href="page1.html">page 1</a> 
            <a class="menu" href="page2.html">page 2</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="main"> this is page1 <br> click anywhere</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is page2.html:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).toggle(
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "block");},
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "none");
      });

    $('.slider').change(function(){
        var wid= $(this).val() + "px";
        $('#box').css("width", wid);
    });  
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#cfcfcf;
    display:none;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main{
    margin: 50px;
}

#box{
    width:10px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    background:#000;
}

</style>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="page2">
        <div class="navigation">
            <a class="menu" href="page1.html">page 1</a> 
            <a class="menu" href="page2.html">page 2</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="main"> this is page2 <br>adjust box width with slider </p>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <input type="range" class="slider" min="5" max="600" step="1" value="10"/> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got any code/examples/demos for us to look at? It's pretty hard to say what the problem is without seeing anything.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show a sample

Comment: Does each html document have a `head` containing your `css` and `script` tags?

Comment: I added more description of code above. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your css and scripts to each page head tag

---

try this one

```
 <!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">



$( document ).delegate("#page1", "pageinit", function() {     

    $(document).toggle(
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "block");},
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "none");
      });                 
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
.navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#cfcfcf;
    display:none;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main{
    margin: 50px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <a class="menu" href="page1.html">page 1</a> 
            <a class="menu" href="page2.html">page 2</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="main"> this is page1 <br> click anywhere</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And  page2.html ,

```
 <!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>   

<body>


<div data-role="page" id="page2">

 <script type="text/javascript">


$( document ).delegate("#page2", "pageinit", function() { 
    $(document).toggle(
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "block");},
      function(){
      $('.navigation').css("display", "none");
      });

    $('.slider').change(function(){
        var wid= $(this).val() + "px";
        $('#box').css("width", wid);
    });  
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.navigation{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background:#cfcfcf;
    display:none;
}
.menu{
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.main{
    margin: 50px;
}

#box{
    width:10px;
    height:30px;
    margin: 0px 50px;
    background:#000;
}

</style>
    <div >
        <div class="navigation">
            <a class="menu" href="page1.html">page 1</a> 
            <a class="menu" href="page2.html">page 2</a> 
        </div>
        <p class="main"> this is page2 <br>adjust box width with slider </p>
        <div id="box"></div>
        <input type="range" class="slider" min="5" max="600" step="1" value="10"/> 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this one

Comment: Internal stylesheets make the style applied in different pages, but custom script still does not work.For example, I have script to adjust image width, which does not work in a linked html: $('#picture').css("width", slider-value);

Comment: I copied full code for two pages above in my question. Thanks!

Comment: What is the  page loaded first ?

Comment: Ah really? did you also open page1.html first and then click page2 from its menu? it never works in different computers and in different browsers when I tried.

Comment: Ya.. i first opend page1.html and then clicked page2 link. In page 2, slider is working fine.. Can you tell me what is the very first page loded in your applicationn?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with my setting. Whenever I open page 2 from page 1, the box width does not change although I adjust the slider... anyhow thanks for your help!

Comment: oh, I started with page1.html.

Comment: I accepted your answer, just cannot vote right now because of my insufficient reputation point. But I will vote for sure with enough point. Thanks again.